# Own function with .done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, for example:

```
$.fn.print = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

This way, I can simply call

```
$("#myExample").print();
```

But, I would also want to be able to get a .done call working:

```
$("#myExample").print().done(function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

Could somebody point me a direction on how to do so? I found some answers here, but they are over-complicated and I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your function isn't asynchronous, why do you think you need `.done()`?

Answer (score 0):

`.done` is only on deferred objects. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/. Your `.print()` is not creating/returning a deferred object.

Do you mean you want chaining? Like https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining.

```js
$.fn.print = function(prefix) {
  console.log(prefix + ": " + this.text());
  return this;
}

$("#myExample").print("a");

$("#myExample").print("b").text("end").print("b");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myExample">start</div>
```

Comment: Thans for the answer. I was able to make chaining work, but I am looking forward to make the deferred one work.
For some reason some functions are running in parallel and not working. I would like to implement .done in one of them so I can run the other one only when the first is done

Comment: What functions are working in parallel? Show us more code/examples. If you want to do what you want then you'll have to use some deferred objects.